# Unable to render high definition image

Tags: rendering, reflection

I am new to Blender and I am learning to render images in cycles.
Someone told me that higher sample amount will increase the quality of the render, but still, after 1600 samples, my rendered images are not in good quality.
Please help me to understand how I can render images in good quality.
I rendered this wall but when I zoom in it becomes blury[image: this is the wall]

[image: this is rendered result and my settings]

Comment: The quality of the reflection will never be better than the quality of the HDRI. Try using a better quality reflection map in the world properties.

Comment: And set the roughness value of the sphere (closer) to 0 (it's unclear from your image whether the environment map or the material of the sphere is to blame).

Comment: (I also suggested an edit to your post, and am assuming you are wondering about the quality of reflections specifically. If that's not the case, please revert the post back to its original state :)

Comment: Thank for you reply and sorry for the sphere things were not clear in that image but the problem I am facing is not about the reflection its about the  rendered quality

Comment: @Joachim I hope things are clear now so please let me know how can i rendered in good quality

Comment: Well, if the image in your question is a render, of course it will become blurry when you zoom in. Can you please tell us in detail what you're doing and what your goal is? What do you want as a result, and how are your current results inadequate?

Comment: The render quality looks  F I N E  to me. What are you talking about? Are you trying to increase the resolution? That would be in Properties -> Render Output, and will not be affected by samples.

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard yess I want to increase the resolution but its already 1920x1080 but i don't think so my rendered image is in 1920x1080.
do I have to increase it more ??

Comment: @Joachim, I am talking about the resolution.
I want to see the texture and displacement clearly when I zoom..
but in this rendered  image textures are not clear

Comment: Try rendering at a higher resolution and see if that's better (quick tip: you can do basic math in the numerical value inputs in Blender: say the current resolution is `1280`, click to edit, add `*2`, and it will multiply the value by 2). Since the render process likely starts from the center outwards, you don't have to finalize the render to get a good impression of the final quality.

Comment: Thank you guyz now it look much better, but its been 36 minute and it only rendered 20-22% of full image. I am rendering it in 3840 x 2160px.
I have Ryzen 3 3200G with 2GB vega 8 integrated graphics card and 8GB Ram. its showing 5 hours for full image is it normal time or I have to do some changes??

Comment: @blendershishye: For a scene like that, it is a lot of time. However, with only diffuse materials, you can easily dial down your sample count A LOT (assuming you still have it set to 1600). Especially when you make use of the denoiser, then you will probably be fine with 20-50 samples.

Comment: Thank you all I got all the information I needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a higher image resolution. The default resolution is 1920x1080, which means the image is 1920 pixels (little color blocks) sideways, and 1080 pixels up and down. Doubling each to get 3840x2160 will mean that what used to be one pixel will now be four (from 1x1 to 2x2).

Samples is how much data goes into one pixel. In Cycles, a sample is one ray trace from a pixel out backwards into the world, which will bounce uniformly on a shiny object but arbitrarily on a rough object. Too few samples makes rough things like stone look fuzzy, but things like polished metal generally look alright. More samples means more realistic renders, more computation time, and more desire to use GPU compute possibly .

Comment: Thanks brother for detailed information. I was doing it wrong, atlast I used diffused BSDF and image textures this help me to decrease render time and quality was good too

Comment: Praise the Lord.